# How to describe this text alignment feature with varied font sizes

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I see it all the time in Facebook posters and memes where each row of text is of a different sized font, but with the margins justified. There are even [animations that use this feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QU7usI5HBWo). What is this called?

Sample usage: "How to [*my word*]" as a google query.

---

*Reason for asking: I am sure that there must be an automated way of doing this feature without a compass and slide rule, and that such a feature should be "googleable".*

*(The content in these examples happens to be religious as I randomly took the first two examples from my Facebook feed. However, I have seen this feature in political memes and animated infomercials.)*

[image: sample picture with text feature]

**Edit: Add vertical text justification example**

[image]

Comment: This question is better suited for the graphic design area of stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you. Should I double post, and then answer my own question here when I get an answer there?

Comment: It up to you.  I suggested it because there is a word that describes the design style that you posted, and people in the graphic design area know their stuff.  I know how to do this and do it regularly but can't recall the word.

Comment: Ok. I will post there and then follow up here when I get an answer.

Comment: It's not hard to create this effect.  Depends on which program you use, but all of them are capable of this.  A vector based program works best in my opinion.

Comment: It's not new. You'll see it in old adverts, newspapers etc. where it was used for visual effect when using graphics was difficult but the printer had a variety of type sizes on hand. Taking down some old examples may help you find the term.

Comment: Anyone know what's with all the downvotes on the answers?

Comment: @Michael this would indeed be very easy in inkscape (free, any platform) and perfectly possible even in PowerPoint.

Comment: @Daron I haven't downvoted any myself because they may be helpful. But none of them is correct. Some are wrong and the rest too broad.

Comment: I agree that the subject matter is more on-topic on [GraphicDesign.SE]. But I don't think *this* version of the question should be migrated because in its current form it's not a GD question. The obvious answer (particularly for the first example) is that it's justification: set the margins and then alter the type so that it fits nicely. It's possible that there is an algorithm to calculate the text size -- is that what you're asking about? Have a look at typography questions in GD and ask a similar question to this one over there.

Answer (score 1):

An at least related word to what you are asking is copyfitting

http://printwiki.org/Copyfitting

And

https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs200/Adobe/Info7.html

> Copyfitting is the process of deciding which typeface, point size, leading (line spacing), and line length are necessary to fit a certain amount of text into a given space. With careful planning, these choices need only be made once, at the beginning of a job.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](https://www.thewastedspark.com/2019/10/the-block-justified-text-graphic.html) calls the style "**block-justified**" text.

Answer (score 0):

The process of spacing letters apart to determine the total width of the line is called **kerning**. In this poster kerning is used to make each line the same width. Try "How to kern".

Here's a [link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kern) from the HMH Dictionary of the English Language.

Comment: Glad to see you edited your answer from a question. It would be nicer if you could include any reference/research/link in a dictionary into your answer.

Comment: Kerning is used when the letters are all the same size.  In this case, they are not.  The letters were converted into text outlines and then expanded keeping the aspect ratios locked.  If you'll notice, the Kerning is the same for all lines.

Comment: I'm not sure which aspect ratios you are referring to. But look at the distances between the W and A of "WAY" on the second and fifth lines. It is about the same on each. So the letters of the second line are (proportionally if not absolutely) more widely-spaced.

Comment: To get this effect, you create outline from the text, group the outlines, then lock the aspect ratios, so that when you expand the entire group of letters they expand proportionately.  Otherwise, when you expand the group it will expand unevenly.  I suppose you could increase the font size until it matches the margins...but that will not create a perfect alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any word specifically coined to represent 'where each row of text is of a different sized font, but with the margins justified.'

However, I believe that ***typography*** would be a suitable word to encompass the meaning of the situation.

Through changing the font sizes or fonts but keeping the margins aligned, you are changing the ***typography*** of something.

> *Typography*
>
> the style and appearance of printed matter.
>
> • the art or procedure of arranging type or processing data and printing from it.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to justify changing the font size mid-sentence :P

Comment: But perhaps there is more to it than that. Usually when you justify you just space the letters as necessary. But in this case some of the letters have had their proportions stretched to fit as well. For example compare the Ws of the first and last "WAY"s

Comment: Thanks @Daron. I misread the answer and changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The text in the poster uses [**justification**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Justified).

> A common type of text alignment in print media is "justification", where the spaces between words, and, to a lesser extent, between glyphs or letters, are stretched or compressed to align both the left and right ends of each line of text.

Fully justified text is also known as "**[flush left and right](https://wmich.edu/writing/readability)**":

> Justified alignment—**flush left and right**—compresses or expands letter and word spacing to fit a given line and can produce awkward hyphenation of words.

(Originally cross-posted with @Ronald, then deleted, now undeleted as @Ronald changed his answer.)

EDIT: If you need a Google query, try "[How to justify text](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22How%20to%20justify%20text%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=wDc2VoyzNcTDOor6m4AP)".